# Nested loop (FOR) with IF statement inside 2nd for print just one result

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested

Basically I have 2 arrays, one with some code and another with codes and relative description, what I need to do is match the codes and print the description but my code (apparently) stops at the first loop of the inner FOR (I've attaches a screenshot to understand better).
If I remove the IF statement from the code it prints the counters of the 2 for as it should be.

[image: Nasted loop js]

```
for (x=0; x<causeoferrorlength; x++)
{
    document.getElementById("mdataresult").innerHTML += "x "+causeoferrorsplit[x]+"</br>";
    for(k=0; k<78; k++)
    {
        if ( causeoferrorsplit[x] === gbrucausesoferror[k][0] )
        {
            document.getElementById("mdataresult").innerHTML += "k "+gbrucausesoferror[k][0]+"</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I have no errors from the console but it isn't printing as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably better handled in a [declarative way versus imperative](https://codeburst.io/imperative-vs-declarative-javascript-8b5e45a602dd). It will be shorter and easier to reason about.

Given you're using two arrays, and that the codes in the first array will always be found somewhere in the second array:

```
let causes = ["001", "003", "005"];
let codes = [
        ["001","Earthquake"],
        ["002","Sunspots"],
        ["003","User Error"],
        ["004","Snakes"],
        ["005","Black Magic"]
];
let results = causes.map( cause => codes[ codes.findIndex( code => code[0] === cause ) ][1] );
console.log(results); // ["Earthquake", "User Error", "Black Magic"]
```

What's happening here? We're mapping the array of potential causes of error (the first array) to a list of descriptions taken from the second array.

- Array.map takes a function that is invoked once with each array member. We'll call that member 'cause'.
- Array.findIndex takes a function that is invoked once for each array member. We'll call that member 'code'.
- For each 'cause' in causes we find the index in codes where the first array value is equal to the cause, then return the second array value, the description.

If you have the ability to change the second array to an object, then this gets way simpler:

```
let causes = ["001", "003", "005"];
let codes = {
  "001":"Earthquake",
  "002":"Sunspots",
  "003":"User Error",
  "004":"Snakes",
  "005":"Black Magic"
};
let results = causes.map( cause => codes[cause] );
console.log(results); // ["Earthquake", "User Error", "Black Magic"]
```

Comment: Wooo.. That's the best explanation ever.. Thank you so so much, today I'll try this way